# Reverse engineer SAS code to create a mapping document

Tags: sas

I have inherited a large base of SAS code. I need to reverse engineer to create some mapping document, so that given a field in the final output dataset, we can easily trace it all the way back to one of the inputs.

I can create it by hand, but can SAS automatically generate something like this?

Comment: You can try PROC SCAPROC, but that's what documentation is intended to accomplish. Sadly, its the step skipped most often.

Comment: Do you just have the SAS code or the  SAS DI Studio jobs? if you had DI Studio you can create documentation and do impact analysis by few clicks.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think there is any ready-made automated way of doing this.

Bear in mind that it is possible to create variables and pass them through a whole series of procs and data steps without mentioning them by name anywhere in the source code. Some sort of run-time analysis is therefore unavoidable.

Reeza's suggestion of using `proc scaproc` will yield some useful information for code executed within a single self-contained job running in a single SAS session, and the `ATTR` option in the `record` statement might be of some help to you when tracing the lineage of variables, but I'm afraid that however you approach this, it's going to take quite a lot of work.